# How to resolve the problem of P2P Connection for 3 layers of NAT

Tags: client, p2p

Currently, I am doing a project which remoting a toy car under the cellular network which is a P2P connection.

I required to use PC (WiFi Connection) to control the toy car (Data hotspot connection) and transfer packet by using UDP.
It seems like have some issue within it, first for all will be the CGNAT problem. I know we can use the UDP hole punching but it is hard for me do to this due to I am weak knowledge on this area.

I would like to ask is there any way still can be implemented for the P2P connection if a VPN is available?

Answer (score 0):

check out [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/)

> ZeroTier combines the capabilities of VPN and SD-WAN, simplifying network management.
>
> Emulates Layer 2 Ethernet with multipath, multicast, and bridging capabilities.
>
> ZeroTier provides network control and P2P functionality.
>
> Use ZeroTier to create products which run on their own decentralized networks.
>
> Access your desktop, NAS, and other devices from anywhere